# How to serialize python script across servers?

Tags: python, attributes

I started using Prefect recently and I noticed I can add decorators to some methods then submit them to prefect. It will then run my script remotely on an agent server. I'm wondering how it is possible to use an attribute and to serialize a method somehow for remote execution.

Example Prefect python script

```
import sys
import prefect
from prefect import flow, task, get_run_logger
from utilities import AN_IMPORTED_MESSAGE


@task
def log_task(name):
    logger = get_run_logger()
    logger.info("Hello %s!", name)
    logger.info("Prefect Version = %s ", prefect.__version__)
    logger.debug(AN_IMPORTED_MESSAGE)


@flow()
def log_flow(name: str):
    log_task(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = sys.argv[1]
    log_flow(name)
```

Comment: I don't see you using an attribute on a function in the code you posted. Are you sure you're using the correct nomenclature?

Comment: @brunson forgot they are called decorators in python, have updated my nomenclature.

Comment: That makes more sense, but it's still a little unclear. Are you asking how prefect works? How it accomplishes the feat of running a function on the remote server?

Comment: I'm unsure how I could collect information from a method to run it on another server. It would be very convenient to be able to serialize a python script from centralized server and run it on a worker somewhere else.

Comment: There are many ways to serialize a function. Python can do it with the `pickle` module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: you can always send all code in file as text, and run as normal python on other side. BTW: using `print( perfect.__file__ )` you should get path to source code and you can try to understand source code.